# c# 2 or more query in 1 command MySql

Tags: c#

I just wanted to ask how to get my value from table1, table2 and table 3. What I wanted to do is to get My firstname on table1 and then I want to get my lastname from table 2 and my address from table 3 and pass the value of 3 to a string. Just educational purpose. I'm not sure again whether I use MySqlDataAdapter or MySqlDataReader

I'm doing a sample project using windows application form c#. Below is my code.

```
     using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connstring))
     {
     con.Open();
     MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM table1, table2, 
     table3", con)
     //I removed my code here because it doesn't making any sense due to the  
     fact. I'm not sure with my MySqlCommand.
     con.Close();
     }
```

Comment: See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1):

Using JOIN command you can combine your query.
For example (using SQL syntax instead MySql):

```
Select * from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t1.PrimaryKey = t2.ForeignKey
    left join table3 t3 on t1.PrimaryKey = t3.ForeignKey
```

Where PrimaryKey is PK first table, ForeignKey - your FK for children tables(base on your relation).
Sure you can use different way of JOIN like left or right, based what query you need.